# Writing down a Hamiltonian that couples spin and phonons

Tags: quantum-spin, time-evolution, phonons, spin-models, spin-chains

I am studying spin dynamics and am trying to write down a Hamiltonian that couples the spins with the phonons. I have the following interacting spin Hamiltonian

$$H_{s}=\sum h_{i}S_{i}+H_{\text{Heisenberg}}+H_{\text{Anti-symmetric}},$$

where $h_i$ is the onsite random magnetic disorder. Further, I also have the Hamiltonian for phonon modes as follows

$$H_p=\sum_kb_k^{t}b_k\hbar\omega_k.$$

How do I proceed to write the Hamiltonian $H_{sp}$? I searched online and studied quite a few papers, but was not able to find any explicit Hamiltonian that expresses the coupling. Is there any way to add the spin interactions with the phonon modes that is analytically or numerically easy to work out?

Answer (score 0):

Equation (5) of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.inorgchem.9b01407) says that, for weak coupling,
$$H_{s,p}=\sum_k q_k \frac{\partial H_s}{\partial q_k}\bigg|_0,$$ where $q_k$ is the eigenvector of the $k$th normal mode (ie, the spatial mode of the phonons).

In general, I would expect weak coupling to take a form similar to the [Jaynes-Cummings model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaynes%E2%80%93Cummings_model): something like
$$H_{s,p}\propto \sum_{k} g_k(b_k+b_k^\dagger)S_x\approx \sum_k g_k(b_k S_+ + b_k^\dagger S_-)$$ (there would be various coupling constants $g_k$ and the $\approx$ would hold in the rotating wave approximation.

Comment: I had read that before and that paper seemed non-intuitive to me. Is it possible to write coupling in term of $H= \b{S}\dot Phonon term$ i.e $Sx.Phonon$+$Sy.Phonon$+$Sz.Phonon$??

Comment: Yes, that can work. The first equation of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.93.257205) says explicitly that $H_{sp}\propto\mathbf{S}\cdot\mathbf{\Omega}$, where "$\mathbf{\Omega}$ is the angular velocity of the local rotation of the crystal due to a transverse phonon."
There are also many more details in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.72.094426), where the main problem with expressing the coupling explicitly is that one needs to compute how the phonons rotate the fields inside the crystal.